# Removing all eventListeners by class

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am using the first code block to successfully add eventListeners to a group of `<div>` tags with the same class, but the second block, which is almost identical, does not remove them. Can someone explain why this is?

1.

```
let names = document.querySelectorAll('.playerName');
names.forEach((name) => {
    name.addEventListener('click', () => {selectSelf(name)});
});
```

2.

```
function dropEvents() {
    let drops = document.querySelectorAll('.playerName');
    drops.forEach((drop) => {
        drop.removeEventListener('click', () => {selectSelf(name)});
    });
}
```

They are both selecting the same group of `<div>` tags with class `.playerName`. The `selectSelf(name)` function that runs on `click` only assigns the value of the clicked `<div>` to a variable, runs an `alert()` (just so I can know it successfully ran) and then immediately calls the `dropEvents()` function. So in theory `selectSelf(name)` shouldn't run after the first time, but it does.

For the `.removeEventListener` method, I've tried many different variations with no success.

EDIT: I saw on the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp) page for this method that anonymous functions won't work, which sorta changes my question. I tried the following, but it didn't work either.

```
function dropEvents() {
    let drops = document.querySelectorAll('.playerName');
    drops.forEach((drop) => {
        drop.removeEventListener('click', selectSelf);
    });
}
```

Comment: Arrow functions are anonymous and cannot be back referenced but the 2nd argument to removeEventListener() must be a function reference.

Comment: Because you're attaching functions that you don't keep a reference to, about all you can do is a deep clone and replace the node with the clone. That will remove all listeners added using *addEventListener*, but not inline listeners.

Comment: In order for `removeEventListener` to work, you have to pass it the _same_ function that you passed into `addEventListener`, not just one with the same code.

Comment: Don't trust w3schools, the site has many errors, use MDN instead. You can remove anonymous functions, you just have to keep a reference to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2nd argument to removeEventListener() must be a *reference* to the function *that is assigned to the event as listener* but you are passing a *new*, literal arrow function.

In the example, the 2nd occurrence of `() => {selectSelf(name)}` is a *new* arrow function declared literally. The one that was already added as an event handler is a *different* function so you cannot expect it to be removed.

To make it work, save a reference to each handler function that you can later pass to `removeEventListener()`:

```
let names = document.querySelectorAll('.playerName');
const handlers = [];

names.forEach((name) => {
    // Use a unique identifier for each function reference
    handlers[name.id] = () => selectSelf(name);
    
    name.addEventListener('click', handlers[name.id]);
});

function dropEvents() {
    let drops = document.querySelectorAll('.playerName');
    drops.forEach((drop) => {
        drop.removeEventListener('click', handlers[drop.id]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, correct. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks!! This did it.

Answer (score 2):

The signature / reference of the event handler must be the same. In your code, during remove, you must refer to the same function. Below is the solution. Move the `click` event handler to a function.

```js
let names = document.querySelectorAll('.playerName');

const clickEv = () => {
  // selectSelf(name);
  console.log('yay');
};

names.forEach((name) => {
    name.addEventListener('click', clickEv);
});

function dropEvents() {
    let drops = document.querySelectorAll('.playerName');
    drops.forEach((drop) => {
        drop.removeEventListener('click', clickEv);
    });
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="playerName">1</button>
<button type="button" class="playerName">2</button>
<button type="button" class="playerName">3</button>
<button type="button" class="playerName">4</button>
<button type="button" class="drop" onClick="dropEvents()">drop</button>
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to what OP is trying to do because OP's event handlers referene the `name` closure variable. Seems you just commented that out because you didn't know what to do with it.

Comment: I am commenting out because there's no `selectSelf(name)` function provided. The question owner can uncomment it and try.

Comment: That wouldn't work because `name` would have no value. You've moved the function out of the context where `name` would have had a value.

Comment: Following up on what people are saying, this doesn't address needing pass `name` to the `selectSelf(name)` function.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `removeEventListener` to work, you have to pass it the *same function* that you passed into `addEventListener`, not just one that looks like it.

A complication in what you're trying to do is the use of the closure variable `name`, which creates a situation where each separate handler function is a unique, anonymous function, so that would leave you having to keep track of all the functions you used and then reference them again in order to remove the handlers.

But that's really not needed here. `name` is just a reference to the element itself, which you can obtain from the event parameters (`e.target`).

And if you do that, you can just use an ordinary, named function instead of creating a separate function for each element and having to keep track of them:

```js
let names = document.querySelectorAll('.playerName');

// placeholder
const selectSelf = (el) => console.log(el.textContent);

const clickHandler = (e) => {
  selectSelf(e.target);
};

names.forEach((name) => {
    name.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});

function dropEvents() {
    names.forEach((drop) => {
        drop.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    });
}

document.getElementById('drop').addEventListener('click', dropEvents);
```

```html
<div class="playerName">Glorgon</div>
<div class="playerName">Marlbratt</div>
<div class="playerName">Xaxir</div>
<div class="playerName">Splengraf</div>
<button type="button" id="drop">Drop Events</button>
```